# How to compare two lists?

Tags: compare

As shown below, the code fails to redefine the color when it is white (e.g. rgb(1,1,1)).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
   \foreach \code/\col in {%
   {1,1,1}/white,
   {1,1,0}/yellow,
   {1,0,1}/pink
   }{

   \ifx {\code} {1,1,1}
   \definecolor{tempcolor}{rgb}{1,0,0}
   \else
   \definecolor{tempcolor}{rgb}{\code}
   \fi
   \textcolor{tempcolor}{\col};
   }

\end{document}
```

[image]

Why is my condition failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**REVISION**: Your original attempt works almost literally.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
   \edef\speciallist{1,1,1}
   \foreach \code/\col in {%
   {1,1,1}/white,
   {1,1,0}/yellow,
   {1,0,1}/pink
   }{

   \ifx\code\speciallist
    \definecolor{tempcolor}{rgb}{1,0,0}
   \else
    \definecolor{tempcolor}{rgb}{\code}
   \fi
    \textcolor{tempcolor}{\col};
   }

\end{document}
```

[image]

**OLDER ANSWER**: Ti*k*Z comes with all the tools to compare these lists, you do not need to load additional packages. (BTW, you also do not have to load `xcolor`.) In more detail, Ti*k*Z allows you to parse lists (or arrays), and this allows you to define a quantity that is 0 if all entries coincide with your target list and 1 otherwise. In more detail, I compute a quantity

```
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myx}{sign(abs({\code}[0]-{\speciallist}[0])+abs({\code}[1]-{\speciallist}[1])+abs({\code}[2]-{\speciallist}[2]))}
```

where

- `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` ensures that one gets an integer, such that `\ifnum`, which only works for integers, works.
- the argument is `|first entry of \code - first entry of \speciallist|+|second entry of \code - second entry of \speciallist|+|third entry of \code - third entry of \speciallist|`.

Clearly, this quantity is only 0 if all the entries of the lists coincide. Here, `{\code}[0]` evaluates to the first entry of the list `\code`, and so on.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
   \edef\speciallist{1,1,1}
   \foreach \code/\col in {%
   {1,1,1}/white,
   {1,1,0}/yellow,
   {1,0,1}/pink
   }{
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myx}{sign(abs({\code}[0]-{\speciallist}[0])+abs({\code}[1]-{\speciallist}[1])+abs({\code}[2]-{\speciallist}[2]))}
   \ifnum\myx=0
    \definecolor{tempcolor}{rgb}{1,0,0}
   \else
    \definecolor{tempcolor}{rgb}{\code}
   \fi
    \textcolor{tempcolor}{\col};
   }

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!  Do you mind to explain or point where to get more info about this? \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myx}{sign(pow({\code}[0]-1,2)+pow({\code}[1]-1,2)+pow({\code}[2]-1,2))}

Comment: @TonyTan I added an explanation to my answer. `\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myx}{sign(pow({\code}[0]-1,2)+pow({\code}[1]-1,2)+pow({\code}[2]-1,2))}` is very similar except that one takes the second power of the differences rather than computing their absolute values.

Comment: @TonyTan A slight variation of your original proposal works, and is much simpler.

Comment: very nice.  Thanks again for your time and efforts! @marmot

Answer (score 1):

You're technically hoping to see whether `\code` equals `1,1,1` as a *text string*. You can use `\pdfstrcmp{<strA>}{<strB>}` for this. It returns -1/0/1 if `<strA>` is smaller than/equal to/greater than `<strB>` (lexicographically):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\foreach \code/\col in {%
    {1,1,1}/white,%
    {1,1,0}/yellow,%
    {1,0,1}/pink%
  }{

  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\code}{1,1,1}=0
    \definecolor{tempcolor}{rgb}{1,0,0}%
  \else
    \definecolor{tempcolor}{rgb}{\code}%
  \fi
  \textcolor{tempcolor}{\col};
}

\end{document}
```